# display google chrome local storage in options page of a chrome extention

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to display the previously saved chrome local storage, the console.log line does show the saved data correctly in console bit in the HTML page I only see  the first line of the js file "This is what was saved in storage",

the HTML of the options page is:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      
  
  <head>
      <title>Price Comparator</title>
      
      
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
      <h1>Price results</h1>
      
      <div id="slideContainer"></div>
  
  
  
  </body><script src="options.js"></script>
  
  </html>
```

the options.js:

```
    var str = 'This is what was saved in storage:<ul>'

async function enumStorage() {
    const all = await chrome.storage.local.get();
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(all)) {
        str += '<li>'+ key + " "+ JSON.stringify(val) + '</li>';
        
    }
    str = JSON.stringify(str);
    console.log(str)
   
  }

enumStorage();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

    document.getElementById("slideContainer").innerHTML = str;
})
```

Comment: Your script already runs when DOM is loaded so remove DOMContentLoaded listener and just assign the element.

Comment: Thank you, that was the answer, can you please mark this answer as an answer and not a comment so I can mark it as answered